# Splitting Environment.NewLine not working

Tags: c#, .net, string, split

Actually,My application has DevExpress `ASPxMemo` Control and I am getting text from it into a `string` and splitting it by :

My Input in `ASPxMemo` is

```
1
2
3

4
5

string[] arr = answer.Split(new string[] { "\n", "\r\n" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

and in my PC I'm getting it in a correct way and the array `arr` Length is showing as `5` when Debugging.
But,When I host it on server(`Windows Server 2012`),I'm getting the array(`arr`) Length as `1`.
What might be my problem??

Comment: Have you tried Environment.NewLine? I think your problem lies with the ASCII standard, it might got changed when you transfered your files to the Windows Server 2012.

Comment: I don't know the character it is generating for NewLine.

Comment: What is exactly the `answer`?

Comment: actually,user need to enter minimum 2 lines of code and if he doesn't,then it will show an error message.
ryt now,I'm getting an error message,even if we enter 3-4 lines

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should split on every possible scenario, such as: "\r" , "\n", "\r\n" and Environment.NewLine (because you did not know which character will be inserted on clientside) and remove this undesirable chars which stays in lines.